# How to symbolically define set of all real numbers (R) in set-builder notation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Can we define R using set-builder notation without language semantics (purely in math symbols)?

Is it valid to do the following: $\{x\in\mathbb{R}|x\}$

Comment: First off, it would just be $\{x\in\mathbb R\}$. Second, this is quite redundant, since you define $\mathbb R$ with $\mathbb R$

Comment: To avoid the baggage that 'define' carries with it, you might say 'write' or 'denote' instead.

Comment: The bar is only used to specify restrictions on the elements of the set. In your case, the $x$ is not only redundant but incorrect because $x$ is not a condition on $x$.

Comment: No. You use one vertical bar, or colon, to separate the base set from all the restrictions. In your example, $y$ and $n$ have no meaning.  Take a look at https://www.mathsisfun.com/sets/set-builder-notation.html

Comment: If you were forced to use the bar, as in a software package, you could do something like $\{x\in\mathbb R| 1=1\}$ but I have never seen that. You only use set builder notation when there are restrictions. Without restrictions you just say $\mathbb R$.

Comment: It is the set with no restrictions. In your case, it is $\mathbb R$. By the way, "base set" is not standard nomenclature. It is how I describe the set with no restrictions. I apologize if that confused you.

Comment: $\mathbb R$ is the base set and $x\ne 0$ is the restriction. Note that you can combine restrictions as in $\{x\in\mathbb R|x\ne 0 \land x\lt 5\}$.

Comment: There is never more than one bar in set builder notation. Please visit the link I gave you. It even has a quiz to see if you understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual format for describing a set using set-builder notation is:

$$\{\text{what elements of the set look like} \mid \text{what needs to be true of those elements}\}$$

where the writing after the vertical bar is a property (or several properties)  that needs to be true about the object named (or 'instantiated') before the bar.

So, something like $\{x \mid x\in \Bbb R\}$ is more usual. And this just says that our set consists of all things $x$, where $x \in \Bbb R$.

Another example: the set of even integers could be written as $\{2k \mid k \in \Bbb Z\}$. This says that for every integer $k$ (i.e., $k \in \Bbb Z$) we put the integer $2k$ in our set. Or, that our set consists of things of the form $2k$, where $k$ is an integer; all the integers that are multiples of $2$ (the even ones).

Or, you could write the set of even integers as $\{n \mid \text{$n$ is an even integer}\}$, or $\{n \mid n = 2k \text{ for some } k \in \Bbb Z\}$. There are lots of possibilities.

---

Your particular example, writing the set of real numbers using set-builder notation, is causing some grief because when you *define* something, you're essentially creating it out of thin air, possibly with the help of different things. It doesn't really make sense to define a set using the set you're trying to define---and the set of real numbers takes a surprising amount of work to really define adequately, by a mathematician's standards.

But you don't really care about that, you just want to practice set-builder notation. Hence my suggestion to say that you only want to 'write' or 'denote' the set of real numbers. That sets aside the circularity inherent in *defining* the set of real numbers, *using* the set of real numbers.

---

No matter what, it's going to look pretty weird writing a set using set-builder notation, *using* the set we're trying to write. Once you get used to it, you'll see that doing that always looks 'the same', e.g. $\Bbb Z = \{n \mid n \in \Bbb Z\}$.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you could find a way to do it without any language semantics but you can define $\mathbb{R}$ as the limits of $\mathbb{Q}$-cauchy sequences.

Comment: Because that's circular reasoning? You can't use something to define itself. @bp2017

Comment: @bp2017 So tell me then, what does $\mathbb R$ represent? If I were to make a non-math analogy, this sounds like you are trying to explain to someone who's never eaten pizza before what a pizza is by saying, it's a pizza!

Comment: Well, one construction of the set $\mathbb{R}$ is the collection of limits of $\mathbb{Q}$-cauchy sequences. One cannot make a pizza without first knowing what cheese, and tomatoes, and so on are.